# How to change the height of a HTML table when a link is clicked?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Hi I would like to change the height of a HTML table from 690 to 400 in the 2 seconds in a smooth transition by clicking a button. Is there a way to do this in pure CSS? Here is my example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="690" width="1280> <--- This cell needs it height to change to 400px when the button is clicked.
Cell 1
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that purely with `CSS`, however you can easily do it with `jQuery`:

```
// Use a more specific selector by ID or class
$('button').click(function (event) {
    $(this).closest('tr').next().children('td:first').animate({height: 400}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Javascript.
Use `function click() {
document.getElementById('id').setProperty('style', 'height:100px;');
}`

And for the button use this - `<button onclick="click();">BUTTON</button>`

Answer (score 0):

give id to button (clickbut) and for the table(tableheight)
then use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clickbut").click(function(){
    $("#tableheight").css('height','somevalue eg:300px');
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow, this worked great, thanks! Is there a way to make it move smoothly, like a transition?